# Using strings and arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

So here is my assignment: Write two programs: one using the String class and one using the StringBuffer class. Your programs should store a set of Strings in an ArrayList and print those Strings in the order by which they are added. The output of your programs should create a complete sentence.

And I think I created the first one:

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayListExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    String i1="H";
    String i2="e";
    String i3="l";
    String i4="l";
    String i5="o";

    arraylist.add(i1);
    arraylist.add(i2);
    arraylist.add(i3);
    arraylist.add(i4);
    arraylist.add(i5);
    System.out.println(arraylist);
  }
}
```

But my teacher does a good just of making us write programs without teaching us how to do it. So I don't know how to create that using the "StringBuffer class" So could someone atleast explain to me what it is? Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)? Also, you can't print an array like that. It won't even compile.

Comment: Tell your teacher that we use StringBuilder nowadays when we want to concatenate Strings especially in this kind of case where it is not meant to be shared so you don't need it to be thread safe

Comment: @Nfear FYI it compiled and ran fine just now when I tried it. (But I wasn't certain it would.)

Comment: If I read the assignment correctly, the output needs to be a SENTENCE, not a list of words separated by commas (which is what your example does.)  So the question is how to append an ArrayList of words together into a sentence, a) using String, and b) using StringBuffer. I suspect you are supposed to put whitespace between the words as well. Hopefully your teacher gave you sample output to clarify these points.

Comment: @Bampfer you are right, was fighting some fiddle shenanigans ;) I don't think the result will be accepted, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("H");  
sb.append("e"); //now original string is changed  
sb.append("l");
sb.append("l");
sb.append("o");

System.out.println(sb);//prints Hello
```

Now go ahead and take look at the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html